# Convert a folder of images into a dataset of numpy arrays in Google Colab

Tags: python, image, numpy, google-colaboratory

I have uploaded the fairface dataset (https://github.com/joojs/fairface) into my google drive and I'm trying to convert the images to a dataset of arrays that I can use in a CNN.

First, I created a list of the files for the validation set. Now I am trying to convert the images to arrays. This is what I am trying, but it says my directory does not exist.

val is the folder of validation images.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

val_items = os.listdir('/content/val')
train_items = os.listdir('/content/train')

val_img_array = []
# load the image and convert into 
# numpy array
for i in range(len(val_items)):
  img = Image.open('/content/val/*.jpg')
  numpydata = asarray(img)
  val_img_array.append(numpydata)
  print(val_img_array)
```

Please give me any guidance you have. Thanks!

Comment: Two things: 1. If you want to use relative path, drop the `/` in front of your paths. Might be the issue. 2. `Image.open` has a  wildcard `*`, but I believe you have to specify a valid filename here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing the drive correctly. Your path should look like this:

`Image.open("/content/drive/MyDrive/val/")`